# Solve the congruence by using the method of completing the square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Actually, I found a open problem which is the same as my problem, see [Solve quadratic congruence equation by completing square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957602/solve-quadratic-congruence-equation-by-completing-square). But I can not understand the answers...they are too brief...

My typical method to solve a prime power $p^r$ modulus congruence is first solve the corresponding $p$ modulus congruence and then rise the solution in some way. For example, to solve the congruence $x^2 +x+7=0$ (mod $27)$, I will first solve the congruence $x^2 +x+7=0$ (mod $3)$ and the only solution is $1$. Then, with the same trick used in the open problem, we can rise the solution, and finally get the solutions of the congruence modulo $27$.

But my textbook requires me to solve this problem with the method of completing the square. And it provides me of a hint that $4x^2+4x+28=(2x+1)^2+27.$ However, I have no idea about this hint. And the textbook never mentions the method of completing the square.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to solve $$4x^2+4x+28\equiv 0\pmod{27}\ \text{ or } \ x^2+x+7\equiv 0\pmod{27}$$?

Comment: Note $2\times14+1\equiv0\pmod{27}$

Comment: Isn't it $2\times 14\color{red}-1\equiv 0\bmod 27$ @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Yes, I meant 13

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Sorry for my late reply. I wanted to solve the second one but actually these two congruence are equivalent in that $(4,27)=1$, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Good inspection too :) But, hmmm, it seems like that we missed the other two solutions, i.e. $x\equiv 4$ mod $27$ and $x\equiv 22$ mod $27$...

Comment: You’re right @Sam Wong

Comment: Since $27$ isn’t prime, there can be more solutions to $u^2\equiv0$ besides $u\equiv0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I see. Can you help me check if my comment below the post of WillJagy is correct? Thanks!

Comment: @SamWong:  How about this:  If $9$ does not divide $u$ then $81$ does not divide $u^2$ so $27$ does not divide $u^2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Your argument makes more sense. I found a flaw in my reasoning. Because $u$ may not be powers of a prime, I can not argue in that way. Thanks a lot Tanner, sincerely. You helped me a lot in my study of elementary number theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the square is simply adding some amount and subtracting it in order to get *partially* a square. Consider for instance $x^2+2x=x^2+2x\underbrace{\color{green}{+1-1}}_{=+0}=(x\color{green}{+1})^2-1$...

Your textbook suggests that $$x^2+x+7\equiv 0\bmod{27}\stackrel{\cdot 4}{\iff}4x^2+4x+28\equiv0\bmod {27}$$ $$\iff \underbrace{(2x+1)^2}_{=4x^2+4x+1}+27\equiv(2x+1)^2+0\equiv(2x+1)^2\equiv0\bmod 27\iff \ldots$$ 
I obtained $$x\equiv\begin{cases}4\\13\\22\end{cases}\bmod 27$$

Comment: You mean mod $\color{red}27$

Comment: mod 27 for the last part perhaps

Comment: $\color{red}{27}$

Comment: And again, thanks for pointing the typo out!

Answer (score 2):

if $$  u^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {27} $$
then
$$ u \equiv 0 \pmod 9  $$

so
$$ u \equiv 0,9,18 \pmod {27}  $$

Comment: Thanks Jagy. Your post helped me understand Dr. Mathva's post. But I still have problems in understanding your first step. i.e. How do we know $u\equiv 0\,($mod $9)$ provided  $u^2\equiv 0\,($mod $27)\,?$ Thanks for your elaboration in advance.

Comment: I came up a reasoning and can you help me see if it works. Since $27=3\cdot 3\cdot 3$ and $27\vert u^2 \iff (3\cdot 3\cdot 3)\vert (u\cdot u)$, we know $3\vert u$ and $(3\cdot 3)\vert u$. And so $9\vert u$. Is my reasoning correct? Thanks!